# Drude-Sommerfeld model for the metallic solid: Why does every state occupy a volume of $\frac{\pi^3}{V}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Textbook: Introduction to Quantum Mechanics 3rd Ed. (Griffiths and Schroeter)

I am an undergrad studying quantum physics for the first time (on the second trimester). We are on Chapter 5 of the Griffiths. In section 5.3.1, Griffiths introduces the Sommerfield "electron gas" model of the solid. 
After solving the Schrodinger equation and finding the form of the energy, Griffiths claims

> If you imagine a three/dimensional space, with axis $k_x,k_y,k_z$, and planes drawn in at $k_x = \frac{n\pi}{l_x},k_y = \frac{n\pi}{l_y},k_z = \frac{n\pi}{l_z}$, each intersection point represents a distinct (one particle) stationary state. Each block in this grid, and hence also each state, occupies a volume $$\frac{\pi^3}{V}$$

I don't see why "Each block in this grid, and hence also each state, occupies a volume" $$\frac{\pi^3}{V}$$.

Comment: Assume that you are editing your question at the moment. As a suggestion it would be helpful to mention the author of the book your are quoting from.

Comment: $\Delta k_x\times \Delta k_y\times \Delta k_z=\pi^3/(l_x l_y l_z)=\pi^3/V$.

Comment: But why the $\Delta k$'s to begin with?

Comment: you want the size of a cell made from adjacent values of $k$, i.e. at location along $x$ $(n\pi/l_x)$ and $(n+1)\pi/l_x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi$ seems to appear out of nowhere in this derivation. In my opinion, this should read $\Delta k_d=2\pi/L_d$ ($L_d$ being the side lengths of a 3D bulk cube), and then multiply over all 3 dimensions in k-space to get to a volume in k-space: $(\Delta k_d)^3=8\pi^3/V$.

The $2\pi$ is the normalization constant of the Fourier transformation (which is chosen dependent on the scientific field, usually).

The $\Delta k$'s represent the distance between the quantum mechanical states of a particle in bulk 3D. The density of states in k-space is the inverse of the distance between the states. Usually, the calculation goes on to expressing it as a function of energy $D(E)$ as described [here](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter2/ch2_4.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The vector $\vec{k}$ uniquely labels all possible states. So for your system, the set of possible states form a 3D grid, each point labelled by a unique $\vec{k}$.

The distance between each grid point is $\pi/l$ and in each volume element of $\pi^3/V$ there is only one k-point.

An analogous case of 2D is graphically shown below.

[image]